# Flask form.validate_on_submit() does not respond

Tags: python, flask, form-submit

I am trying to create a Flask app in which you can search 'car_name' term and it will return a HTML template in which car_name is replaced with 'car_name'. form.validate_on_submit() has no errors, but when you click on the Submit button nothing happens. 
I have looked at similar questions, but they-re all about errors while in mine, nothing happens (no errors, but no response either).
Any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

This is my main application code:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request, redirect
from wtforms import Form, StringField, SelectField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required


#Flask application object
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'jacky'


class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    motor_name = StringField("", validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home') 
def index():
    form = SearchForm()
    print(form.errors)
    motor_name = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        motor_name = form.motor_name.data
        return redirect(url_for('car', car_name=motor_name))
    return render_template('homepage.html', form=form)


@app.route('/car/<car_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def car(car_name):
return render_template('carpage.html', car_name=car_name)
```

And this is the homepage.html code

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.protein_name.label }} {{ form.protein_name() }}
{{ form.submit() }}
```

Comment: do you have `<form action="/" method="POST">` ?

Comment: you have mistake - you use `protein_name` in template but in form you defined `motor_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 3 mistakes in code and I saw error messages when I ran code in console/termina/cmd.exe.

First: you used `proteine_name` instead of `motor_name` in template.

Second: you forgot `<form method="POST"></form>`

Third: you forgot to import `url_for`

It is strange that you didn see errors.

---

I used `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` only to easier run code with all in one file.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, render_template_string
from wtforms import Form, StringField, SelectField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required


#Flask application object
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'jacky'


class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    motor_name = StringField("", validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home') 
def index():
    form = SearchForm()
    print(form.errors)
    motor_name = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        motor_name = form.motor_name.data
        return redirect(url_for('car', car_name=motor_name))
    return render_template_string('''<form method="POST">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.motor_name.label }} {{ form.motor_name() }}
{{ form.submit() }}
</form>''', form=form)


@app.route('/car/<car_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def car(car_name):
    print('car_name:', car_name)
    #return render_template('carpage.html', car_name=car_name)
    return render_template_string('car_name: {{car_name }}', car_name=car_name)

app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After adding <form action="/" method="POST"> and import url_for, when I click Submit it redirects to carpage.html, however it does not display my search term where car_name is (motor_name = form.motor_name.data, return redirect(url_for('car', car_name=motor_name)) and return render_template('carpage.html', car_name=car_name), meaning that in retrospective, car_name in carpage.html should be form.motor_name.data)), do you have any idea why this is not working?

Comment: `car_name=car_name` in `render_template('carpage.html', car_name=car_name)` means that it will be avaliable as `{{ car_name }}`, not `{{ form.motor_name }}` - like in my code `render_template_string('car_name: {{car_name }}',...)`

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)